# Function that accepts parameter and returns +1

Tags: javascript

```js
addOne= function(num) {
    return num + 1;
}
```

why is this not working? Huge brain fart on functions.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where is function call ? where you're passing parameter ? how function is invoked ?

Comment: Are you passing a Number? Or a string?

Comment: It is working? Whats the problem? Please provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var addOne= function(num) {
    return num + 1;
}

console.log(addOne(1));
```

You have to declare the function and call it, then you have to pass an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love online threads...down voted and locked for asking a question on stackoverflow.

Is there another site I can actually ask questions on?